# $\prod_{n}f_{n}$ converges uniformly $\Rightarrow $ $\sum_{n}\mathrm{Log}(f_{n})$ converges uniformly

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, reference-request, infinite-product

Let  $\prod_{n}f_{n}$ be an infinite product of holomorphic functions on a given domain $\Omega$ converging uniformly on compact subsets  of $\Omega$  to $f$.

Then is it true that $\sum_{n}\mathrm{Log}(f_{n})$ converges uniformly on compact subsets 
(avoiding zeroes of all $f_{n}$ and of $f$) to $\mathrm{Log}(f)$ for appropriate branches of the logarithm?

Are there any books which analyze this questions ?

Comment: On compact sets avoiding zeroes of all $f_n$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Do you have some references ?

Comment: ... and also assuming the limit $f$ is nonzero (which in some treatments is part of the definition of "converging" for infinite products).

Comment: @WLOG apply the appropriate $\log$ to the partial sums, and use uniform continuity (on compacta).